# How Can I Edit Storyboard Source Without Losing Formatting?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes it is very convenient to open a storyboard as source and edit the xml. Almost exclusively I will be moving things around. For instance: I will change the order of the scenes in the document outline.

Whenever I cut from one spot and then paste into another all of the line indentation is lost; all lines begin in column 0. I must then tediuosly restore the indentation with a series of select -> Cmd-] operations.

Does anyone know how to prevent this and/or how to easily restore the indentation?

Comment: Best bet is to use a better source editor.  I use sublime for this kind of thing.

Comment: Thx, Lou. I happen to have Atom; worked like a champ!